# How to make ListView render next nearest item instead of keeping both the items half in view port of ListView?

Tags: flutter

The behaviour that is required is to move to next item or previous item based on scroll but don't keep both the items in view port. Like Instagram reels and shorts render only one video in list at time.

ListView

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      controller: scrollController,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return iStreamWidget.render(data[index]);
      },
    );
```

Comment: you can set list item widget  height according to device full height.

Comment: that doesn't work you can still have half items and it's not locking view to nearest item